# Why isn't +setup in my testcases being called when I create a custom test suite with XCTest?

Tags: xctest, xctestcase

I have a subclass of XCTestSuite that I instantiate and populate with tests on the fly:

```
+ (XCTestSuite *)defaultTestSuite {
    MySuite *suite = [[MySuite alloc] initWithName:@"suite"];
    [suite addTest:[[MyTestCase alloc] initWithSelector:@selector(firstTest)]];
    [suite addTest:[[MyTestCase alloc] initWithSelector:@selector(secondTest)]];
    return suite;
}

+ (void)setUp {}
- (void)setUp {}
- (void)firstTest {}
- (void)secondTest {}
```

The `-(void)setUp` is being called for each test, but `+(void)setUp` is never called. If I don't use my custom testSuite or I call:

```
 + (XCTestSuite *)defaultTestSuite {
    XCTestSuite *suite = [super defaultTestSuite];
    [suite addTest:[[MyTestCase alloc] initWithSelector:@selector(firstTest)]];
    [suite addTest:[[MyTestCase alloc] initWithSelector:@selector(secondTest)]];
```

it does get called. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCTest has a private internal class called `XCTestCaseSuite` that is a subclass of `XCTestSuite`. You can see the Swift source [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/blob/master/Sources/XCTest/Private/XCTestCaseSuite.swift). It is what is responsible for calling `+(void)setUp` for you. If you want this same functionality, you will have to duplicate it in your custom `XCTestSuite` subclass. I couldn't find documentation for this anywhere, but it does make some sense in that if test cases are coming from different classes, how do you order when the `+(void)setUp/+(void)tearDown` methods are called.